# principle component analysis - manual calculation - problem finding axis and eigenvectors on approximated covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, numerical-linear-algebra

For the sake of a future tutorial video, I'm trying to manually perform the calculation of the principle axis and associated variances.

Of course i'm trying to compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance matrix. The problem is that while i can calculate with no pb the eigenvalues, i can't calculate the coefficients of the eigenvectors :

It's a very simple 2D toy example, the covariance matrix is :

$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
2.5 & 2.1 \\
2.1& 3.7
\end{pmatrix} 
$

I computed the eigenvalues as : 0.81 and 5.38 . Using the gaussian elimination, I tried to manually solve the equation

$(C - 0.81 I_2) \vec x = \vec 0$

I end up with : $\vec x = \begin{pmatrix}
0  \\
0
\end{pmatrix} $
 while computing the eigenvectors with octave gives me the 2 eigenvectors : $\vec x_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
 -0.79801 \\
0.60265
\end{pmatrix} $ and $\vec x_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
 0.60265 \\
0.79801
\end{pmatrix} $

I guess the more general and deeper questions are :

- Is there a solution to the equation $A \vec x = \vec 0$ when A is full rank ?
- The coefficients are approximation, is there a problem solving this equation and computing reduced row echelon form with real type values or approximation ?

Thank you

EDIT : my original set of toy data is : 
$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
 2, 3 \\
 3, 4 \\
 4, 5 \\
 5, 6 \\
 5, 7 \\
 2, 1 \\
 3, 2 \\
 4, 2 \\
 4, 3 \\
 6, 4 \\
 7, 6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: You always have $A 0 = 0$. I don't know what you mean by coefficients. Coefficients of what?

Comment: I edited my post, hopefully it's easier to understand. How do i find non-trivial solutions to this equation ?

Comment: If the eigenvalues of $C$ are non zero, then the **only** solution to $Cx=0$ is $x=0$ since $C$ must be invertible.If you want to find an eigenvector you need to solve $(C-\lambda I)x = 0$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: I forgot to mention it in my post but that's what i did - thank you i will edit it

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question:

In order to get the eigenvectors corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, you need to fine nontrivial solutions of $$(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=\vec{0}.$$

If $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue, then this will only have the trivial solution. In particular, when $A$ is of full rank, then $0$ is not an eigenvalue and $A \vec{x}=0$ will only have the trivial solution.

For the second part of the question, I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but: If you don't use the exact value of the eigenvalue (because of numerical approximation of a real number), then you won't be able to find nontrivial solutions. Note that the eigenvalues of your example matrix are roughly $0.92$ and $5.28$, but not exactly these values.

Comment: I guess the differences in the results we obtained for the eigenvalues are the result of approximation from my original datas and covariance matrix and errors when i manually computed them